# Image centered in Firefox but not IE

Tags: image, internet-explorer, firefox

Can anyone tell me why the logo on this page is not centering in IE?

http://www.cateringvisions.com

Comment: Just for reference: I assume you're going to fix the centering problem as soon as the right answer appears.  So the link isn't going to mean much to future generations of web designers who have the same problem.  It'd be better if the CSS and HTML were somewhere where the answer wouldn't inherently change them -- like here in the question.

Comment: The markup in this site is rough, I would drop the tables and use a CSS layout instead. You will be producing much better quality and accessible site in the end.

Answer (score 0):

HTML 4 Transitional invokes quirksmode. use `<!DOCTYPE HTML>` in place and it should work.

EDIT:

http://www.cateringvisions.com/topframe.html

^ This page needs a standard dtd. BTW, you should not be using framesets in 2010.

http://hsivonen.iki.fi/doctype/

^ Page listing dtds and modes.

Comment: I thought having any valid doctype line triggered standards mode (if it's a full declaration, including the DTD URL, and is the very first thing in the document).

Comment: @cHao: I thought so too, but a quick look at the Developer Tools told me it was really in Quirks Mode... maybe Google knows what's going on? :)

Comment: Maybe it has something to do with the site using frames, but not using the frameset DTD.  Will an invalid tag cause the parser to fall back to quirks mode?